# I have issue with kinematic equation in my homework

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

I'm trying to solve this task. The body moves in a uniform field of gravity of the Earth. Resistance force
the medium is proportional to the square of the velocity. In the initial moment of time, the body was at a height of H, and its speed was zero. To find the dependence of speed on time, speed on height, and height on time. I assume that I should use newton's second law and the conservation of energy law. But I'm stuck with formulas and don't understand. Is this the right way? I think the formula for velocity will be too complicated after solving

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are going right except for the last two steps, your differential equation is correct just integrate to find velocity as a function of time( the integral will include log) once you have velocity as function of time write velocity as dx/dt on integrating again you will get displacement as a function of time

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Homework and "check my work" questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. Please read [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) on asking homework questions and [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic) for "check my work" questions.

Comment: energy is not conserved with friction/drag forces present. (Airline travel would be much cheaper if it were).

Comment: The expression (1/2)at^2 for distance is valid only with constant acceleration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track to calculate $v(t)$ with the first two equations. Extract a factor of $k/m$ out of the rhs of the second equation, move some parts around and we have
$$
\frac{dv}{gm/k-v^2} = \frac{k}{m}dt,
$$
from which you can start the integration (take care of some minus sign btw) to obtain $v(t)$. After that, continue to integrate $v(t)$ w.r.t. $t$ to obtain $h(t)$. To have a quick check of your answer, see if $v(t)$ approaches the [terminal velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_velocity) as $t \to \infty$, and see if $h(t)$ behaves as a linear function of $t$ as $t \to \infty$.

However, $v(h)$ is probably hard to obtain, as can be seen from the expression of $v(t)$ and $h(t)$ respectively.